# \veqref{} command like \vref...from varioref package

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

1) The `varioref` package gives `\vref`, which gives output as follows...

> figure~`\ref{fig:test}` on page~`\pageref{fig:test}`.

2) The `amsmath` package gives `\eqref{}`, which gives output as follows...

> equation (1.5) ie instead of printing a plain number as 1.5, it will print (1.5)

Now, the question is... is there any command like "`veqref`", which can give out put as

> equation~`\eqref{eq:test}` on page~`\pageref{eq:test}`, something like equation (1.5) on page 30

I did not know how to do this...

---

Thank you cmhughes for the answer...

I added Eq.~ as follows...

```
\labelformat{equation}{Eq.~\tagform@{#1}}
```

A little more example...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varioref}


% this bit makes sure that the number is typeset upright- needs amsmath
\makeatletter
\labelformat{equation}{Eq.~\tagform@{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
Bla bla bla...
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2+\sin(x)
\end{equation}
Here is a reference: \vref{eq:myequation}.
\emph{Here is another reference: \vref{eq:myequation}.}

\clearpage
Bla bla bla...\\
See \vref{eq:myequation} and use it.

\chapter{Two}
Bla bla bla...\\
See \vref{eq:myequation} and use it.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Section 2.3 of the documentation details that you can use

```
\labelformat{equation}{(#1)}
```

so that `\vref` works as you would want it to for equations.

In fact, following egreg's comment, one should have the reference typeset upright, even if it is contained in environment that is (for example) italic.

[image]

A complete MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varioref}

% this bit makes sure that the number is typeset upright- needs amsmath
\makeatletter
\labelformat{equation}{\tagform@{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2+\sin(x)
\end{equation}
Here is a reference: \vref{eq:myequation}.

\emph{Here is another reference: \vref{eq:myequation}.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to take a look at the package [cleveref](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref). According to its description:

> [t]he package enhances LaTeX's cross-referencing features, allowing the format of references to be determined automatically according to the type of reference. The formats used may be customised in the preamble of a document.

I use it myself, and it is very flexible and configurable.

And here is a MWE, showing the use of `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2+\sin(x)
\end{equation}

Here is a reference to \cref{eq:myequation}. 

Here is a reference to the number alone:
\labelcref{eq:myequation}.

\emph{Here is another reference, see the upright  
reference number without any additional commands or  
packages:
 \cref{eq:myequation}.}

\end{document}
```

The use of `labelformat` in `varioref` has some limitations, which are described on page 5 in [cleveref’s manual](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf). `cleveref` has its own `labelformat`, also described in the manual (for more advance users).

You do not need to name the figure, tables or the page. A reference to an equation on another page in your manuscript is written:

```
See \cref{eq:myequation} on \cpageref{eq:myequation}
```

Comment: Hi Sveinung, It is useful if you give a minimum working example.